# How to export a csv file from a mysql server using a C# application and get all column names in the top of the exported csv-file

Tags: c#, mysql, csv

I looked for a similar question but didnt find a solution for my problem. I developed a C# program which communicates with a mysql server.

I try to export a table from the mysql server to a csv file including the names of each column in the top. It's working, but theres a problem. When I use the following code:

```
string query = "SELECT /*here i insert column names*/ 
UNION SELECT /*here i insert column names*/ 
FROM `tableName` INTO OUTFILE /*here I insert the path*/ 
\ FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
```

It works, but I have to write each column. Is there a possibility to avoid that? So I could use the * operator so it looks like:

```
string query = "SELECT * 
UNION SELECT * 
FROM `tableName` INTO OUTFILE /*here I insert the path*/ 
\ FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
```

Because this Code is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all column names from your table with following statement:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Bundle'
```

Export your rows -> Get all column names using above statement -> Write your result to the beginning of your file using C#

This is how I would do this. Another possibility is a dynamic pivot which is much more complicated.

**EDIT**

Since OP mentioned that he may not have access to the exported file, here is a quick and dirty statement achieving the wanted result:

```
DECLARE @DataList varchar(500);
SELECT @DataList = COALESCE(@DataList + ',', '') + 'CAST(' + COLUMN_NAME + ' AS varchar(255))'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOURTABLE'

DECLARE @PivotList varchar(500);
SELECT @PivotList = COALESCE(@PivotList + ',', '') + COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOURTABLE'

DECLARE @GroupList varchar(500);
SELECT @GroupList = COALESCE(@GroupList + ',', '') + 'MIN(CAST(' + COLUMN_NAME + ' AS varchar(255)))'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOURTABLE'

DECLARE @Query varchar(1000)
SET @Query = '
SELECT ' + @GroupList + ' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
PIVOT
(MAX(COLUMN_NAME) FOR COLUMN_NAME IN (' + @PivotList + ')) AS B
WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''YOURTABLE''
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
UNION ALL
SELECT ' + @DataList + ' FROM YOURTABLE'
EXEC (@Query)
```

I hope this works for you!

Regards.

Comment: Yeah, i already tried this one, but then the problem is that the column names are in rows and not in columns...so I can't use the union command to combine them to the other data!

Comment: You have n rows in your text file (because you exported it earlier) like so:

    Val1, Val2, Val3
    Val21, Val22, Val23

Now you do execute the query i suggested above where you are going to get 3 rows Like this:

    Col1
    Col2
    Col3

You open your created textfile. Jump to the beginning and for every row you fetched with the suggested statement you insert the value, with your seperator.

In the end you have a textfile like this:
    Col1, Col2, Col3
    Val1, Val2, Val3
    Val21, Val22, Val23

Comment: well, I can't say right now, that the c# application will be able to write to the exported csv-file. Usually I want that the server keeps the control about the exporting file...

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope this is going to work now for you!